# pass json data ajax from php but time is change in php when data get

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, datetime, jquery-week-calendar

i write code for event calendar in `jQuery plugin` when i send data from ajax to php for store event in `database` my time is different in JavaScript and php

my time in `JavaScript`

> Tue Jan 02 2018 09:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

when i get this date time in php my time is

> 2018-01-02T03:30:00.000Z

i have i can get exact `date time` which i send from `ajax`

my ajax code

```
$.ajax({
 type:"POST",
 url:"eventCreate.php",
 data:{data:enc},
 cache: false,
 success:function(result){
   alert(result);
 }
});
```

`data` i have to pass

```
{start: Tue Jan 02 2018 09:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), end: Tue Jan 02 2018 09:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), id: 10, date: Tue Jan 02 2018 09:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), title: "", …}
body
:
""
date
:
Tue Jan 02 2018 09:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) {}
end
:
Tue Jan 02 2018 09:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) {}
id
:
10
start
:
Tue Jan 02 2018 09:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) {}
title
:
""
__proto__
:
Object
```

and now how to get exact `datetime` in php

my php code

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test");
$data = json_decode($_POST['data']);

$query="insert into event_calendar (`event_id`,`start_time`,`end_time`,`date`,`title`,`body`)
     values('".$data->id."','".$data->start."','".$data->end."','".$data->date."','".$data->title."','".$data->body."')";

echo $query;
```

Comment: create a variable and assign the time value in that and pass that.

Comment: Post your php code, too.

Comment: Javascript is the clients time, PHP is the servers time.  You can send the time to PHP ( from the client ) and then convert it using PHP's date time funcitons.

Comment: You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all!

Comment: You do get the exact same time. JS shows it in `GMT+0530` and PHP shows it in `GMT`. Same date/time, different time zones. Saving it normalized as GMT is a good thing. Then you decide what time zone it should be when you present the date.

Comment: sorry its `$data->date` not `$date` @mega6382

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to change the default time zone in php

```
date_default_timezone_set('Indian/Comoro');
```

> set this code in the top of your php file.

also you can find all supported php time zones in [here](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.indian.php)

Also be careful javascript is a client side programming language, so the timezone of your php code might get changed depending on user country!

Try to get javascript time from your server.

Answer (score 0):

Set your local time zone in your `PHP` file, using [date_default_timezone_set()](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_default_timezone_set.asp)

```
<?php
// set local timezone
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test");
$data = json_decode($_POST['data']);

$query="insert into event_calendar (`event_id`,`start_time`,`end_time`,`date`,`title`,`body`)
 values('".$data->id."','".$data->start."','".$data->end."','".$data->date."','".$data->title."','".$data->body."')";

echo $query;
```

[Asian time zones](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.asia.php)